# DOSBOX running external windows program

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos, dosbox

Is it possible to open window's file explorer from Dosbox?
When I try to open it, it shows:

> "This program cannot be run in DOS mode."

I type `run.bat` in dosbox, and I run this file:

run.bat:

```
c:
cd Windows
cd System32
explorer.exe "http:\\test.com"
```

thank you!

Comment: DOSBOX emulates a 16bit _hardware_. `Explorer.exe` is either 32 bit or 64 bit. No chance to run that from Dosbox. You would need an 16 bit browser (if you google, look for "windows 3.1"). But don't expect them to be compatible with modern websites (Java, Flash, .HTML4/5,Silverstar,...)

Comment: @Stephan I don't want to run explorer inside the dosbox. I want the dosbox to open an external windows window of the explorer

Comment: I know. That means, you have to start `explorer` on your physical computer (different from the emulated 16bit "computer") This translates to " how do I run a program on a different computer". There are tools to do so (like `psexec`) but I don't know any 16bit versions.

Comment: @Stephan ok got it. You can post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOSBOX emulates a 16bit *hardware*. `Explorer.exe` is either 32 bit or 64 bit. No chance to run that from Dosbox. You would need an 16 bit browser (if you google, look for "windows 3.1"). But don't expect them to be compatible with modern websites (Java, Flash, .HTML4/5,Silverstar,...)

You don't want to run explorer inside the dosbox, but want the dosbox to open the explorer of your guest system (your physical computer, not the emulated 16bit DosBox-Computer)? This translates to "how do I run a program on a different computer". There are tools to do so (like psexec) but I don't know any 16bit versions.